# Chrome Developer Tools caches old version of JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm experiencing a strange intermittent issue with Chrome Developer tools hanging on to old versions of JavaScript files. I'll be developing some JS app, things humming along just find, and then all the sudden my JavaScript files will disappear from the list of JavaScript files on the "sources" tab. This is my first clue that something is wrong.

What I eventually discovered is that Chrome Developer Tools is, apparently hanging on to an old version of the JavaScript file. Chrome itself is requesting and executing the latest version from the server, but you can't debug the JavaScript file.

I "proved" to myself that this was what's happening by taking a particular JavaScript file that had disappeared from my sources list, and replacing it with a one line `console.log` statement.

I then reloaded the page, and noted that the console.log statement appeared in the JavaScript console. I also noted in the Network tab that the JavaScript file was successfully retrieved, and that what came down over the wire contained just the one line `console.log` statement.

However, the JavaScript file still didn't appear in the sources list, and if I clicked on the filename in the console (where it appears on the righthand side of the console, next to the logged statement), then I jump to the sources tab, and an old version of the JavaScript file is opened.

This JavaScript file is loaded onto the page via a regular `<script>` tag. It is not loaded dynamically, via another script, or via eval. Just a plain, vanilla `<script>` tag that points to the .js file on the webserver.

I've tried:

1. Ensuring that "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" is checked in the DevTools settings.
2. Manually clearing out my cache and cookies in Chrome.
3. Restarting Chrome
4. Manually loading the JavaScript file in a separate Chrome tab
5. Disabling every Chrome extension/app that I have installed
6. Running the page in incognito mode
7. Uncheck both "Enable JavaScript source maps" and "Enable CSS source maps"

None of these changed the behavior. You can [watch a video demonstrating this here](http://www.screencast.com/t/YWaRwg5Bbb), if you don't believe me!

I do think it's a Chrome issue, as I can use Firefox without this issue... but I really like Chrome and Chrome's developer tools :-) So I'd like to get this working in Chrome...

**Update** I reported this as a Chrome bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369797). If this bug is affecting you, or important to you, please vote it up and/or add comments with additional information.

Comment: Are you using VS and/or IIS, perchance? I run into this every now and again, I just `Ctrl`+`F5` until it *finally* refreshes the cache. I'll be interested to see if you find a solution.

Comment: If it looks like a bug, then report it: http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Do you have any workspace mapping configured?

Comment: @Cory, I am not using VS or IIS on this project. The webserver is Apache on Windows 8.1 and the IDE is JetBrains PhpStorm (similar to WebStorm + PHP support). I've basically been following the same procedure as you. Reload, reload, reload, reload, reload... and *eventually* it works. No rhyme or reason I can determine.

Comment: @mistaecko, I don't have any [workspaces](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#workspace) configured in Chrome Developer Tools. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: yes. I noticed file refreshing problems similar to yours, and I think attributed them to the workspaces feature.

Comment: The other culprit could be source maps. I did TypeScript development a view months back and the refreshing problems were driving me nuts at times. Source Maps support was still rather new back then, and I think the situation improved with subsequent Chrome releases. EDIT: Just noticed your update on source maps. Keep us updated.

Comment: Sadly, the issue recurred for me this morning even though I have source maps disabled. And, just to be sure, i tried in incognito mode, which disables all my extensions (I have no extensions approved to work in incognito mode), so it's not an extensions issue.

Comment: I reported as a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369797

Please vote up if you are experiencing this issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug 7 years ago. It is still happening in 2021. Firefox had a similar bug, which also took many years to fix.

Comment: I tried clearing my cache and I have this issue in Chrome and Firefox any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Chrome DevTools works fine for me. When I load it for a page it remembers beyond the lifespan of the chrome process what sources I have open; although it gets the order wrong. I see two differences in our devtools prefs: disable cache and enable maps. So I would advise:

1) uncheck disable cache (while DevTools is open),
2) (if 1 didn't work) press the "Restore defaults and reload" button.

Comment: Your solution worked. Clearing cache also worked (Settings/History/Clearing browsing data) for some time. This happens to me when I have Javascript files with breakpoints open in Developer Tools debugger.

Comment: Yes, for me a breakpoint triggered this error too. I have added that to the bug report.

Comment: Yes, clearing cached files in my google chrome fixed the issue immediately. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, clearing cached files in my google chrome fixed the issue immediately. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, clearing cached files in my google chrome fixed the issue immediately. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, clearing cached files in my google chrome fixed the issue immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue persists in 78.0.3904.97. To fix it run settings > advanced > reset.

Answer (score 0):

Some code editors such as rubymine cache js files.

To solve for rubymine: File > Invalidate Cache/Restart

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, only I was using PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/2rolf--fJ3M/UTJQaZN3K28J, for development environment I added these headers when serving a sourcemap:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

and it seems to do the job (at least for now).

Comment: That would not resolve the purpose of editing the javascript while still in chrome.

Comment: I tried that too but it did not remove the problem. It seems Chrome is not even trying to ask my server for the resources it has already cached. Therefore does not matter what response-headers I try to put into the response.