# Why is there a difference in chrome between the index.hmtl file and the view element section?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am running a basic javascript file for a game. I am trying to change the div class player-name to be customized but for some reason when I change the text, it does not update to the screen. In this example, there is no text written in the div element in the HTML file in the sources page.. Yet words display on the screen. When I rightclick on the element and view page source, text comes up that I have not written. Is this a bug in chrome or am I missing something obvious?

I have
1) cleared caching history in chrome
2) exited and restarted chrome
3) exited and restarted sublime text.
4) read this post but with no luck. [Chrome Developer Tools caches old version of JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398854/chrome-developer-tools-caches-old-version-of-javascript-files)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent catching add this lines in your HTML below the Head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />
<meta expires="Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
<meta pragma="no-cache" />
```

BTW, do you know that to clear the chace of your testing page you can long press the Reload Button and choose the last option? this while having the DevTools opened.

Answer (score 0):

The Elements tab shows a representation of the current state of the DOM. This updates as scripts make modifications to the DOM.

The Sources tab just shows the original source code that was parsed when the files were loaded. It will also include anything that's added to the source code flow by `document.write()` during loading (I suspect if you reopen the document with `document.write()` later on, it will replace this, but I haven't confirmed it). But changes made to the DOM by scripts after the page is loaded are not shown here, they're not part of the page's source code.